Cleanup PostgreSQL connections after `drizzle-kit push` with postgres.js client
I'm using the postgres.js (3.4.4) client with drizzle-kit (0.24.1) to run drizzle-kit push, but then I notice it wastefully leaves behind persistent connections.
I know I could run a cron job to periodically cleanup idle connections in PSQL but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner or more idiomatic way to do this.
// drizzle.config.ts
import type { Config } from "drizzle-kit"

import { env } from "~/env"

export default {
  schema: "./src/db/schema.ts",
  dialect: "postgresql",
  dbCredentials: { url: env.PSQL_URL },
  schemaFilter: [env.PSQL_SCHEMA],
} satisfies Config

